# Making the " ' " symbol closer to the variable

Tags: symbols, superscripts

I have the following symbols in a paper I'm writing:

```
\hat{c}_{\omega l}^\dagger {}' {}'
```

and

```
\hat{c}_{\omega l} ''
```

[image]

I would like the double dashes of the daggered term to sit adjacent to the dagger (a similar aesthetic to the non-daggered term). But I can't seem to achieve this adequately. The `{}' {}'` is necessary otherwise Overleaf gives me the 'double superscript warning' since there is already the `^{\dagger}` superscript and otherwise

`\hat{c}_{\omega l}^{\dagger ''}`

produces an undesirable result, where the double dashes are now superscripted.

[image]

Any help on this is appreciated!

Answer (score 25):

The apostrophe is essentially equivalent to `^{\prime}`, which is the reason for the output you get from `^{\dagger''}`. It's a very handy shorthand in most cases, compare `f'(x)` with `f^{\prime}(x)`. In your case you don't want a second level superscript.

Solution: use `\prime`.

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}

\[
\hat{c}_{\omega l}^{\dagger\prime\prime}
\]

\end{document}
```

[image]

A couple of remarks. I often see, for instance in Math.SE, things such as

```
f^{'}(x)
```

which is wrong. The apostrophe has an implicit `^`, so that's equivalent to `f^{^{\prime}}(x)`.

Second remark: `'` is equivalent to `^{\prime}` for a *single* apostrophe; however TeX sets things up so that more apostrophes in a row become `^{\prime...\prime}` (with the correct number of `\prime` tokens) *and* allows a further superscript; thus the square of the second derivative in a differential equation can be typed in as

```
y''^2
```

Unfortunately, this cannot work when the prime *follows* a superscript and `c^{\dagger}''` would raise a “double superscript” error, solved, as said before, with `c^{\dagger\prime\prime}`.

Comment: A side-note... The extra part of `'` beyond `^\prime` is look-ahead for another `'` character or a superscript, to combine them into one superscript. So if the desired symbol was `\hat c_{\omega l}''^\dagger` it would have worked automatically.

Comment: @egreg Great, thanks for this simple answer!

Answer (score 4):

I added, instead, a little answer using also as the user @egreg double `\prime` symbol with `eqparbox` package.

```
%% Compile and read me!
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{eqparbox}
\begin{document}
$\hat{c}^{\eqmakebox[aaa]{$\dagger\prime\prime$}}_{\omega l}$
\end{document}
```

[image]

As in the comment of @campa, I'm adding also the solution with the `\scriptstyle \prime\prime`.

```
%% Compile and read me!
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{eqparbox}
\begin{document}
$\hat{c}^{\eqmakebox[aaa]{$\dagger\scriptstyle{\prime\prime}$}}_{\omega l}$
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: At the very least please put a `\scriptstyle` in there...

Comment: @campa :-) is it too big? Now fix it. :-) Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

Load `mathtools` and use

```
$\hat{c}_{\mathrlap{\omega l}}^\dagger {}'' $
```